# AJAX not returning any JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am able to type a URL to a remote site and it returns json displayed in the browser.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: url,
    Origin: 'http://google.com',
    crossDomain : true
})
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(jQuery.parseJSON( xhr ));
});
```

The ajax call above just returns some object with a readystate of 4 and and a status of 200- but no json or data for that matter, what can I do to retrieve the data?

Comment: Are you able to provide the value for url so we can try it?

Comment: @ThisClark unfortunately, no- security risk

Answer (score -1):

Please check parameter of url, due to you use get method.
The status 200 is good. Please check at back-end.

you can run url on browser to test

Comment: I don't have access to the backend. I did test in the browser, it returned JSON

Comment: please try change 'dataType: 'jsonp'" to "'dataType: 'json'"

Comment: @user3541964 this should be a comment rather than an answer,  which may be why you got downvoted.If you don't have enough reputation to comment then editing questions will help you gain reputation, so will deleting answers with downvotes. You can also edit your answers at any time